# LD_LIBRARY and ldd: cannot open shared object file although it exists

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-libraries

When I try to enable postgis in a postgresql database, it says me:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/home/nadai/compiled/postgres/lib/postgis-2.2.so": libproj.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is:

```
/home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/spatialindex/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/gtest/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/sqlite/:/home/nadai/compiled/gdal/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/geos/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/postgres/lib/:/home/nadai/compiled/readline/lib/:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

while I have this:

```
ldd /home/nadai/compiled/postgres/lib/postgis-2.2.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff55985000)
libgeos_c.so.1 => /home/nadai/compiled/geos/lib/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007fb375bc1000)
libproj.so.10 => /home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/libproj.so.10 (0x00007fb375960000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fb3755d5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb375210000)
libgeos-3.5.0.so => /home/nadai/compiled/geos/lib/libgeos-3.5.0.so (0x00007fb374e68000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb374b64000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb37494e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb37472f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb374429000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb374225000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb37400b000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fb373de9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb376094000)
```

The required file (/home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/libproj.so.10) exists and it is a symlink to /home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/libproj.so.10.0.0.
So I checked the [32 vs 64 bit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314983/ldd-says-not-found-even-though-library-is-in-my-ld-library-path) but I have:

```
file /home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/libproj.so.10.0.0 
/home/nadai/compiled/proj/lib/libproj.so.10.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=6cf84de4cd8a6d702042dafa9cf3568aed011795, not stripped

file /home/nadai/compiled/postgres/lib/postgis-2.2.so
/home/nadai/compiled/postgres/lib/postgis-2.2.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=96af5ffb6691712582874fe90b5e4b47fa3acab7, not stripped
```

What's the problem in your opinion? I'm going CRAZY

PS: (Postgis is installed and compiled in my home directory in Linux.)

Comment: *Your* LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not what daemons run by the system have.  Are you manually running postgressql, or letting it be started by the system?  If the latter, then it doesn't get the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH.